# "Lesson with id=1 has not been found... In integration Tests

Tags: integration-testing

Im using h2 database and writing integration tests. They work separately but when i run them all some of the tests end up with failure because of incorect iD of the objects.

I wrote init() method which saves 2 objects with id=1 and id=1. with @BeforeEach annotation
I wrote teardown method that cleans database with @AfterEach annotation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.